# How to include and link libraries to Octave C++ Dynamically Linked Functions?

Tags: c++, octave, linker-errors, mex, compileoptions

I have an octave DLD function say main.cpp which calls several functions declared and defined(in .h and .cpp files resp) in the directory mathlib/ which is in the same location as main.cpp.

I'm referring to [this](https://docs.octave.org/v4.2.0/Getting-Started-with-Oct_002dFiles.html) octave documentation page for compile options for including and linking libraries

I'm getting the following errors:

```
>> mkoctfile -Imathlib \ main.cpp
g++: warning:  main.cpp -o <PATH>\AppData\Local\Temp/oct-uoZEQc.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: error:  main.cpp -o <PATH>\AppData\Local\Temp/oct-uoZEQc.o: linker input file not found: Invalid argument
error: mkoctfile: building exited with failure status
```

What are the other compile options and steps needed to get the linking to work and compile main.cpp successfully?

Comment: Including a header is *not* linking a library.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Ok, edited out that part. What am I missing in compile command?

Comment: mkoctfile uses the same options as gcc. Read a tutorial or search in SO about compiling and linking in gcc.